# Cant connect with Websocket while using Docker for a node app

Tags: node.js, docker, websocket, dockerfile

Im new to docker and wanted to use it for this Node app with express, SQLite3 and websockets. Everything else is working fine but I cant connect a client to the server websocket.

I have searched around and from what I could find was I had to change the client side code and i have tried a few different things below. I included the error associated to each attempt in the client side code.

serverModel.js:

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server,
  wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 10707 });
```

client (controller.js)

```
  /* Connect to WebSocket */
  // socket = new WebSocket("ws://172.17.0.16:10707"); //
  // socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.65.0:10707"); //Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
  // socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:10707"); //failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
  // socket = new WebSocket("ws://0.0.0.0:10707"); // failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
  socket = new WebSocket("ws://172.17.0.1:10707"); // Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Docker file

```
FROM node:12

COPY . /App
WORKDIR /App

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 10220
EXPOSE 10707

RUN node serverModel.js &
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

I run `docker run -p 10220:10220 -p 10707:10707 -d myname/node-web-app16`

Comment: Hi It is easy to write a simple shell script having those commands (node server Model.js and node app.js) and finally replace last two lines in the dockerfile to CMD ["sh run.sh"]

Answer (score 0):

I hope help you...
First I see that you have some mistakes on your Dockerfile in these lines:

```
RUN node serverModel.js &
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

You cannot use instruction RUN with CMD at the same time using "&".

Second, remember, the instruction **RUN** is only used where you want install some things or execute some instructions to configure the tool like create directories, or create files configuration.

By last, what is your main file, serverModel.js or app.js? if is serverModel.js you need replace app.js with serverModel.js in CMD instruction, and delete the previous instruction (`RUN node serverModel.js &`).

Comment: My main file is app.js, thank you for the help with run i will change that